# Making some kind of reference to objects stored in a vector

Tags: c++, oop, stdvector

I have an `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>>` variable inside a private section of a class. Other parts of the program uses the methods of that class to add elements to the vector. It works, but now I have got a new requirement to allow users of the class remove some elements from the vector as well.

My problem is: I still want to hide the vector from the outside world to keep encapsulation of the class. I thought my methods could just return an iterator to the elements in the vector, but I've read the C++ reference about it and they say, if a vector changes its size, **all** iterators made before are invalidated. So, my second idea was to return an index of the newly added element, but it is also not good for obvious reasons.

So, my question is: how to make an **persistent** reference to an object inside a vector, to be used for deleting the object, *without* exposing the internals of my class too much?

Comment: It's not at all obvious to me why returning an index isn't good, in fact that would have been my answer. Maybe a fat pointer that wraps that index with a pointer to your class and provides some syntactic sugar on accesses.

Comment: What does the API to the class look like? It sounds strange to me that you have a private vector, but want outside members to add/remove specific elements via iterators.

Comment: @Quentin because if someone deletes an object in the vector everyone who stores indexes to objects later in the vector will have their references wrong

Comment: can outside objects just push/pop, or can they remove elements in the middle of the vector? If they only push/pop, then the memory re-allocation doesn't matter if you follow @Quentin's approach and use indices.

Comment: @Felix.leg ah yes, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy and fast solution:

1. Change `std::vector<X>`, to `std::map<int, X>` or `std::unordered_map<int, X>`
2. When adding element generate unique `id` and return it to user. Add element using `id` as key in map
3. When user want to access/delete element he should provde `id`

Comment: If you cant change containers... why not go for a `std::list` or similar? No id generation needed, iterators remain valid.